# Django github git add . does not add static

Tags: git

I did add already few project to github.
Now I created another one in django. I am using Python 3.8 and django 3.2. Exactly the same way as before.

I follow procedure:
I create repo on github.
then in CMD:
git clone https://github.com/my_name/repo_name.git

Then I paste my project there.
Then I follow procedure described here:
https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github

With other project after: git add . I saw all (not sure if all but many of them) files processed on the window. Now after I type git add . it does nothing. There results is that for example it deos not add and does not push static folder at all.

I do evrything the same way as before. When I try to push my old project to github it works. **I have problem with new project in django.**

[Screen shot of git status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD3vl.png)

Comment: What does `git status` say in the new repo?

Comment: I added screen shot of the git status. It also does not add my venv files for the new project.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Don't add your .venv - that can be rebuilt, possibly with the help of your requirements file, so putting it in the repo isn't necessary.

Comment: But it does add evertyhing for the same git hub repo when I use my older django project.

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows that `git add .` worked: the new project's files have been successfully added to the staging area, and they're ready to be committed and pushed.

You'll need to run `git commit` to actually commit the files to the repo. Once that's done, you can `git push` the contents, and any future changes will be tracked.